# R change datatable factor levels using column index

Tags: r, datatable

Assume a datatable DT below

```
DT <- data.table(m=1:3, n=factor(c("a","b","c")))
```

I would like to change the levels of the 2nd column to c("d","e","f"). I can do it using

```
levels(DT$n) <- c("d","e","f")
```

But, what should I do if I just know the column index; i.e. 2. I tried the following line but it doesn't work!

```
i=2
levels(DT[, ..i]) <- c("d","e","f")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , ..i, value = list(n = 1:3)) : object '..i' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still do `data.frame` way:

```
levels(DT[[2]]) <- c("d", "e", "f")
```

Note however it is usually not recommended to update by column index though..